# Flask: render_template with path

Tags: flask

I have several different templates that I'm trying to use for my flask app.

I have tried the following but it seems to only look directly inside /templates and not /templates/folder1, templates/folder2 etc.

```
 return render_template('index.html', template_folder='folder1')
 return render_template('folder1/index.html')
```

both do not work as expected, how can I specify the sub folder of different templates.

Comment: The second should work just fine - what does your directory structure look like?

Comment: inside templates folder I have `folder1` containing index.html and `folder2` containing index2.html

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I think Sean is right, but also: have you tried double quotes? I'm using Blueprint, so it may be different, but this is what mine looks like:

```
return render_template("users/register.html")
```

so yours may be:

```
return render_template("folder1/index.html")
```

Comment: Single, double, or triple quotes in either fashion ... they're all strings, so no difference there. :-)

Comment: never mind i was using index2.html instead of index.html

Comment: This answer is not correct and the question still needs a valid answer as reference.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Single quotes are the same as double quotes.

Answer (score 29):

The template folder can be specified when creating the Flask app (or Blueprint):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='folder1')
```

Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object

```
from flask import Blueprint
auth_blueprint = Blueprint('auth', __name__, template_folder='folder1')
```

Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/#templates

The `template_folder` is relative to where the app/blueprint is located.
Use the `os` library to create paths to template folders outside of the app/blueprint directory.

**eg.**

```
import os
APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(APP_PATH, 'templates/')
```

- run from subdirectory of app root
- APP_PATH retrieves parent directory path (app root)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the Python file and Template folder are all under the same working directory folder.