# Flask cannot find HTML files in templates folder when run through Gunicorn

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, gunicorn

When I run my Flask application directly with Python (developement mode?) everything works fine, so the templates folder is in the right place. When I run it through Gunicorn, it persistently fails to  find my templates folder and thus the required HTML files. I have tried numerous things, such as changing the `template_folder` variable, and the path that is passed to `render_template()` - none have had any impact.

I start gunicorn with `gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 wsgi` (it still doesn't work without wsgi), and everything launches fine.

Terminal:

```
root@vps621912:/home/websites/test2# source test2/bin/activate
(test2) root@vps621912:/home/websites/test2# gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:80 server:app
[2018-12-21 18:13:55 +0000] [30377] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2018-12-21 18:13:55 +0000] [30377] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:80 (30377)
[2018-12-21 18:13:55 +0000] [30377] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-12-21 18:13:55 +0000] [30381] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30381
[2018-12-21 18:14:00,240] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/websites/test2/server.py", line 10, in home
    return render_template('home.html')
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template
    return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template
    return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 58, in get_source
    return self._get_source_fast(environment, template)
  File "/home/websites/test2/test2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 86, in _get_source_fast
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
TemplateNotFound: home.html
```

Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask('__main__', template_folder='../../')


@app.route('/')
def home():
#    return "<h1>test2 - server.py - raw return</h1>"
    return render_template('home.html')
#    return app.root_path


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please make your question self-contained. Don't post links to error messages, put them in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you, sorted it.

Comment: This link can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765692/flask-render-template-with-path?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter given to `Flask` is used to find resources on the filesystem. In your case you are passing `__main__`, which is fine if the entry point to your application is `server.py` - or what you refer to as dev mode. If you use gunicorn to run the application, then your `server.py` script won't be the entrypoint anymore; that means passing `__main__` to `Flask` won't work. Use the following instead:

```
application = Flask(__name__, template_folder='../../')
```

Python sets `__name__` to `'__main__'` when the script is the entry point for the python interpreter. It will evaluate to the name of the module otherwise. Also, note that you have to use `application` as opposed to `app` if you don't specify the app name in the gunicorn command.

This might not work if you are using a package as oppose to a single module to run your app. You can find more info [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#application-object).