# My mp4 won't display in flask when it did before

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

So I was just starting out with flask, and was running through different exercises. Yesterday I deployed a video successfully to my flask webpage, but then today when I ran the same code, I got a black window where the video was supposed to play (image related).

### [image: (image related)]

Here is my flask code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('video.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8000, debug=True)
```

And my HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="file:///C:/Users/(username)/Desktop/Code/Flask/templates/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

My file structure is

```
Flask\
  -app.py (flask code)
  \templates\
     -video.html (html code)
     -sample.mp4
```

Linked videos do work, such as 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-1/ollie.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> <source src="file:///C:/Users/(username)/Desktop/Code/Flask/templates/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
> ```

The problem with this is that this source tag will be rendered in the user's browser and try to resolve the `c:\Users` path to their own machine.

You may wish to approach this by moving `templates/sample.mp4` to `static/sample.mp4` (creating the `static` directory if need be).

Then in the template:

```
  <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sample.mp4') }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Using the `url_for` method, ensures that the correct link is always generated, regardless of the URL which the app is hosted on (eventually).

If you were to instead write `src='/static/sample.mp4'` it would work in development, but if your application is later hosted at `https://example.com/music/` then this link would point to `example.com/static/sample.mp4` when it should be `example.com/music/static/sample.mp4`.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!!! I already had a static and template folder after later troubleshooting, but they didn't work until I switched the source to {{ url_for('static', filename='sample.mp4') }}. Not only did you solve my current problem, but also my next when it comes to actually deploy this. You just made my day!

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `relative address` not `absolute address`

```
  <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
    <source src="./sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: It didn't work, just threw back a 404 error in the terminal. "GET /sample.mp4 HTTP/1.1 404"

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765692/flask-render-template-with-path/48040453#48040453).It seems you just server the `video.html` not the folder.Try to visit `localhost:8080/sample.mp4` to check if it take effects.

Comment: It just threw back. "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."