# html file can not be found in Flask program

Tags: python, html, flask, winscp

I had deployed a flask program using Winscp. my program was working correctly when I run it on the local. but after deploying it using winscp it can not find index.html file.
I had pushed the html files in "templates" folder in the same directory with my python file.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":

        return render_template('ans.html')


    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Although it works correctly in local, there is this type of error when I deploy it using `winscp`. It means when I enter "localhost:5000" link to see index.html file. `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`

Comment: winscp has nothing to do with your problem. You can ask this question to the cloud service provider. he will better assist you here, or specify what cloud service you are using so that some from there can help you here.

Comment: Hi, you might need to give the template path https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21765692/flask-render-template-with-path?rq=1

Comment: this is not the problem because html files are directly  in the templates folder. @IronMan

Comment: The app may be using a different working directory when it launches. Specifying the full path might be needed.

Comment: print(os.getcwd() ) shows the address of winscp in my local machine (in my C drive) @IronMan